# React Native Appium picker

Tags: react-native, appium

We have started developing an iOS/Android app using React Native.  We have automated a lot of our functionality so far using Appium, but have run into a problem with being able to set or select values in a picker (date or choice picker).

I am trying to find if we need to try to fix Appium or look into providing a solution in React Native.  I know native iOS/Android apps have solved this issue in the past couple of years, so hoping someone might have an idea on how to solve it for ReactNative.

An example of what we tried to do with Appium (based on what we did with our old iOS Application).

To pick "Colorado" from a picker, we would do the following:
driver.getElementById("IdOfElementOnPage").sendKeys("Colorado");

The problem is that this does not work.  Even though it can find the field by id, it cannot select the value from the picker.

Here is a screenshot from Appium of the issue.  See how the picker options are just one big blob of text?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5HY6.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should give us a little more to work with... what problem have you run into? What have you tried doing to solve it? An [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates the problem is a great thing to include, if you're able.

Comment: could you share the details corresponding to the picker and what you have tried with that.